# How to look for the following problem in Sequence and Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

It is given that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} a_n$ convergent, but not Absolutely Convergent and $\sum_{n=0}^{n=\infty} a_n= 0$.

Denote by $s_k$ the partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^{n=k} a_n$, $k=1,2,3...$.

Then,

1) $s_k=0$ for infinitely many $k$.

2)  $s_k\gt 0$ for infinitely many $k$, and $s_k \lt 0$ for infinitely many $k$

3) $s_k\gt 0$ for all $k$

4) $s_k\gt 0$ for all but finite values of $k$.

Here $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ works or not?

Comment: Well, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is first of all undefined because the term at $n=0$ is dividing by $0$, and second, if you'd get rid of the first term, it doesn't converge to $0$. You could however do something like $a_0=\log(2)$ and $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ for $n\geq 1$, that'd fix the problems.

Comment: sorry, i make it correct